# What are crew members doing in the Jefferies Tube in "Timescape"?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

In the *Star Trek: TNG* episode "Timescape", the *Enterprise* is trapped in a temporal anomaly that massively slows time.  Picard, Data, and Troi beam over from a runabout in "normal" time, to examine what happened to the *Enterprise*.  They decide to get around in the ship in the Jefferies Tubes, because the turbolifts are not in their time frame, and because they must conserve their own transporter power.

As they descend one particular Jefferies Tube, they find several *Enterprise* crew members blocking their way.

> TROI: Should we go around them?
>
> PICARD: No, we should take another route.

What are these crew members doing in the Jefferies Tube in this scence?  In particular, are they doing something (or headed somewhere) specifically related to the plot of this episode, rather than routine work?

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what they were doing, but whatever they were doing, it was "urgent", required three members of staff and a whole bunch of technology in a junction that leads directly to Main Engineering.

I'd be very surprised if their actions weren't related to the operation with the Romulan ship.

> They come to the hatch in the platform floor. Picard
>       uses a door-opening device (as seen in "Starship Mine")
>       to pry it open.
>
> He stops, startled to see a FROZEN FACE staring right
>       up at him on the other side of the hatch: a CREWMEMBER
>       stopped in mid-climb below, **an urgent look on his face.
>       Two more CREWMEMBERS can be seen behind him, also
>       caught in mid-climb. They are carrying several pieces
>       of (TECH) equipment**, making it impossibly cramped on
>       their side of the Tube.
>
> <sub><sup>http://www.st-minutiae.com/resources/scripts/251.txt</sup></sub>